# How to increase max pool size in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I get the error:

```
Error "ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds.  The max pool size is currently 5; consider increasing it."
```

How do I increase the max pool size?

```
# DB CONNECTION
DB_CONN = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :dbfile => DB_FILE)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
config/database.yml
pool: 8 (default is 5)
```

Read [more](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)

Comment: @PrakashRaman I don't understand your comments. Where did you have to use the `:pool => [int]`? It seems Ruby code not YAML.

Answer (score 1):

A static number of connections can be specified, but ...

```yaml
# config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 99 %>
```

.. but if the number of connections needed is **proportional** to the number of threads, it may be desirable to specify it **dynamically**. In this example, two connections per thread.

```yaml
  pool: <%= 2 * (ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }) %>
```